# Wordpress Multiple Loops Not Displaying on Page

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to run multiple loops on a Wordpress page to display the different posts based on their category. I am using Custom Post Types and a Custom Taxonomy. Can someone let me know what I am missing in my code below? Also, is there a better way to do this?

```
<?php function dd_services_template() {
  $first_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => 'web') );
  $second_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => 'brand') );
  $third_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => 'print') );
  $fourth_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'services', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => 'media') );
?>

<div class="services">
  <ul class="servicesul">
    <?php
      if ( $first_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $first_query->have_posts() ) : $first_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
          <div class="servicestitle"><?php the_title() ?></div>
          <div class="servicescontent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </li>
      <?php endwhile; } ?>

    <?php
      if ( $second_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
          <div class="servicestitle"><?php the_title() ?></div>
          <div class="servicescontent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </li>
      <?php endwhile; } ?>

    <?php
      if ( $third_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $third_query->have_posts() ) : $third_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
          <div class="servicestitle"><?php the_title() ?></div>
          <div class="servicescontent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </li>
      <?php endwhile; } ?>

    <?php
      if ( $fourth_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $fourth_query->have_posts() ) : $fourth_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
          <div class="servicestitle"><?php the_title() ?></div>
          <div class="servicescontent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </li>
      <?php endwhile; } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So... what exactly are you returning with this? The html with empty ul? Any of the queries worked? They all return empty ( 0 values found) ?

Comment: @Clyff Right, the only thing I get is `<div class="services"> <ul class="servicesul"> </ul> </div>`... None of the queries work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i check your code removing

```
function dd_services_template(){
```

and

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>
```

And it's working fine. Just check if you are calling the function correctly.

Btw: i guess you have to close the function after the last `div` tag.

Comment: How do I close the function after the last `div` tag? I don't think I've ever done that before...

Comment: Just move the <?php wp_reset_postdata(); } ?> line to the end. You have a  </ul></div> tags outside. Sorry if i wasn't clear before.

Comment: Ah gotcha... I just did that, but it's still looking the same on the front end.

Comment: Can you show in you question how are calling this dd_services_template() function? Oh another thing, since i dont have this posts_type neither the category, my test had only posts_per_page as arguments. You should check if you have a typo with your args too.

Comment: Ok... I tested the different $args by removing each of them in turn. It looks like the 'category_name' is what is causing the problem. Am I not using the right parameter?

Comment: This is the reference I used to come up with the 'category_name' parameter: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category

Comment: category_name is the slug of the category's post. If you have a category named Web it would be web, just like you are using.

Comment: That's the category I have. I just reverified the different slugs and they are all correct.

Comment: You can always check in you admin menu posts>category what slug each one have. But if you say its all correct i don't know what could be now.